# Accessing foreign key values in django ListView of GCBV

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I have two models related by a Foreign key as follows. (Only shown important fields here.)

**in model:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    ...

class Price(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category) # referred to above model
    sub_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=CHOICE_SUB_TYPE)
    price = models.DecimalField()
    ...
```

I'm going to display Categories in a ListView along with related pricing details. In order do that, I need to set related pricing objects for each Category object. What is the best and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine as it is, in templates, you have access to related models. When listing categories in your template you can:

```
<ul>
{% for cat in categories %}
   <li>{{ cat.name }}</li>
   <ul>
       {% for price in cat.price_set.all %}
           {{ price.price }}
       {% endfor %}
   </ul>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

For displaying categories when showing details for a price, you might want to Use a [Single object Mixin with a ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview).

**Recommended:** [Related object reference.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/)